# Фокус в ScrollView Андроид

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Есть СкролВью с много Вьюшек внутри.

Как установить программно фокус на последнию из вью?

Comment: Если есть,  то добавте код прямо в вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

```
View.requestFocus();
```

В зависимости от типа элемента, может также понадобиться ещё:

`setFocusableInTouchMode(true);`